# Evaluation of Trigonometric Limit Having $3$ variables

Tags: limits

> Evaluation of $$\lim_{(u,v,w)\rightarrow (0,0,0)}\frac{\sin(u^2+v^2+w^2)}{u^2+v^2+w^2}$$
>
> Also How can i justify that the following limit exists.

What i Try

IF $u=v=w=k$. Then $$\lim_{k\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(3k^2)}{3k^2}=1$$

But i did not understand what will happen If any two are equal or all three are Different.

Could some Help me to solve it, Thanks

Comment: $z:=u^2+v^2+w^2,$ $\lim_{(u,v,w) \rightarrow (0,0,0)} z=0$. Then $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1.$

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have a doubt How can i justify that original limit exists

Comment: To show that the limit exists, you can't escape the $\epsilon-\delta$ mess.

Answer (score 3):

The distinctness of the variables doesn’t matter as long as they all tend to a common value. Let $u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = t$. Then as $u,v,w \to 0$ , $ \,t \to 0$. Then the limit simply reduces to 
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin t}{t} = 1$$

Comment: Thanks Tavish. I have a question How can i justify that original limit exists

Comment: @jacky After doing the substitution, you may show that $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\sin t}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0^-} \frac {\sin t}{t}$. It can also be shown graphically.

Comment: Can we prove it By using $\sin(x)<x<\tan(x)$ and applying sequeeze Theorem

Comment: Yes, that is another neat way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the spherical coordinates. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
u = r\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi)\\\\
v = r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi)\\\\
w = r\cos(\varphi)
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow u^{2} + v^{2} + w^{2} = r^{2}
\end{align*}

Therefore the given limit can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(u,v,w)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}\frac{\sin(u^{2} + v^{2} + w^{2})}{u^{2} + v^{2} + w^{2}} = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(r^{2})}{r^{2}} = 1
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is defined as the one that solves the differential equation

$$f'' = -f $$

with $f(0)=0$ , $f′(0)=1$.

From the definition it is direct that

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}x =\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)=1$$

Of course, this is deeply unsatisfactory, because by what right do we take as a definition that the sine solves precisely that differential equation?

Well, that has to do with the fact that $f^2 + (f′)^2$ is a constant function (that is demonstrated by deriving with the chain rule and checking that the derivative is zero everywhere); and evaluating it at 0 it is determined that the constant is 1. Therefore, $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are the lengths (signed) of the legs of a right triangle whose hypotenuse measures 1. On the other hand, with many others accounts it can be shown that $f$ meets the identity of the "sum of angles"

$$f(x+y)=f(x)f'(y)+f'(x)f(y)$$

which gives the idea that x is precisely the angle that makes $f(x)$ the length of the leg opposite x, and $f'(x)$ the length of the leg adjacent to x. With that, the definition above allows to recover the geometric definition, being f the sine function and $f'$ the cosine function.